# How to remove the 'n' number of first or last elements with jQuery in an optimal way?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, dom

I have a table with many rows (+50) and cells (+50). Now I would like to remove the *n* first or last cells with jQuery. Currently I have the following code:

```
var n = 10;
var last = true;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   table.find('tr').each(function() {
      if(last)          
         $(this).find('td:last').remove();
      else
         $(this).find('td:first').remove();
   });
}
```

Note: `table` is a jQuery element.

The code works, but performs *very slow* when I have a table with 50 rows with 50 cells and I remove the 10 last cells. Any ideas how to optimize the code?

***Edit:*** I've added the first clause as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The optimal I think could be using [`nth-last-child`](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).

```
table.find("tr td:nth-last-child(-n+10)").remove();​
```

Benefit is that internal browser CSS selector engine will be used (or in case of IE jQuery will help a little :)
Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krGQc/) removing last 3 elements. Change it to 10 in your case.

Comment: very clever usage of the `n-th-last-child operator`, I like it :)

Comment: This works amazing! I love it... it is small, elegant and performs!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Greater Than](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector. It selects all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set. 
First calculate the number of elements (td). Subtract 10 and then use the greater than selector.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively you could try this.

```
var n = 3;
var len = table.find('tr').length;
table.find('tr:gt(' + (len - n - 1) + ')').find('td:last').remove();​
```